# Approximate family of tempered distributions by Schwartz functions

Tags: distribution-theory, approximation-theory, schwartz-space

I write $S(\mathbb R^d)$ the space of Schwartz functions and $S'(\mathbb R^d)$ the space of tempered distributions.

Assume that I have a family $(u(t))_{t=0}^T \subset S'(\mathbb R^d)$ of tempered distributions such that for all fixed $\phi \in S(\mathbb R^d)$ :
$$\langle u(t), \phi \rangle \in C^0([0,T])$$

Is it possible to find a sequence of Schwartz functions $(u_n(t,x))_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset S(\mathbb R^{1+d})$ such that for all fixed $t \in [0,T]$, $u_n(t, \cdot)$ converges weakly-$*$ to $u(t)$ ?

Here is an inconclusive idea :

One can prove using Banach-Steinhaus that for all $\phi \in S(\mathbb R^{1+d})$ :
$$\langle u(t), \phi(t, \cdot) \rangle \in C^0([0,T])$$

So the family $(u(t))_{t=0}^T$ defines a $(1+d)$-dimensional tempered distribution $u$ using the following formula :

$$\langle u, \phi \rangle = \int_0^T \langle u(t), \phi(t, \cdot) \rangle dt$$

and we can find a sequence of Schwartz functions $(u_n(t,x))_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset S(\mathbb R^{1+d})$ such that

$$\langle u, \phi \rangle = \int_0^T \langle u(t), \phi(t, \cdot) \rangle dt = \lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} \int_0^T \langle u_n(t,\cdot), \phi(t, \cdot) \rangle dt = \lim \limits_{n \to +\infty} \langle u_n, \phi \rangle$$

From here, I couldn't go further. I have no guarantee that $u_n(t, \cdot)$ converges weakly-$*$ to $u(t)$.

Comment: Hello! I don't know the answer, but an idea would be to try and regularize the $1+d$-dimensional distribution in a fancy way, e.g. regularize first in $x$ and then in $t$ (or viceversa). Have you tried that? By the way, do you know if weak-$*$ convergence is equivalent to distributional convergence?

Comment: @LorenzoPompili Yes, distributional convergence is the same as weak-* convergence. I haven't found an answer for this specific question but if we assume that $u(t) \in C^0([0,T],X)$ for some Banach space $X$, then we can approximate $u(t)$ by a simple function $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \chi_{A_i}(t)$, $x_i \in X$, $A_i$ Lebesgue measurable of finite measure, $A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$. Then approximate each $x_i$ and $\chi_{A_i}$ separately with Schwartz functions. This was enough to solve my problem (trying to justify an energy inequality for mild solutions).